# Android NDK and STL-related reference errors on x86

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, v8, embedded-v8

I'm building an integration with the V8 library. This builds works fine for ARM (armeabi, armeabi-v7a) targets.

I want to add x86 support. Today is the first time I've tried this.

I built V8 for x86 via `make ia32.release`.

My `Application.mk` is as follows:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

and `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := v8_libbase
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libv8_libbase.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := v8_base
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libv8_base.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := v8_nosnapshot
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  ./libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libv8_nosnapshot.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := v8_platform
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  ./libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libv8_libplatform.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := v8jsevaluator
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := v8jsevaluator.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := v8_base v8_nosnapshot v8_libbase v8_platform
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c++11
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The build fails in the x86 component with a lot of errors relating to STL.

```
12:13:39 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project v8jsevaluator ****
"C:\\Development\\android-ndk-r10d\\ndk-build.cmd" all 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 9 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
[armeabi] Install        : libv8jsevaluator.so => libs/armeabi/libv8jsevaluator.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libv8jsevaluator.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libv8jsevaluator.so
[x86] SharedLibrary  : libv8jsevaluator.so
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_base.a(assembler.o):assembler.cc:function std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) [clone .part.30]: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::clear(std::_Ios_Iostate)'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_base.a(assembler.o):assembler.cc:function v8::internal::operator<<(std::ostream&, v8::internal::ExternalReference): error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<void const*>(void const*)'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_base.a(assembler.o):assembler.cc:function v8::internal::operator<<(std::ostream&, v8::internal::ExternalReference): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_base.a(assembler.o):assembler.cc:function v8::internal::operator<<(std::ostream&, v8::internal::ExternalReference): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_base.a(assembler.o):assembler.cc:function v8::internal::operator<<(std::ostream&, v8::internal::ExternalReference): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_base.a(assembler.o):assembler.cc:function v8::internal::operator<<(std::ostream&, v8::internal::ExternalReference): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::clear(std::_Ios_Iostate)'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_base.a(bootstrapper.o):bootstrapper.cc:function std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::resize(unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_base.a(code-stubs.o):code-stubs.cc:function std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) [clone .part.32]: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::clear(std::_Ios_Iostate)'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_base.a(code-stubs.o):code-stubs.cc:function v8::internal::CallFunctionStub::PrintName(std::ostream&) const: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_base.a(code-stubs.o):code-stubs.cc:function v8::internal::CallFunctionStub::PrintName(std::ostream&) const: error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_base.a(code-stubs.o):code-stubs.cc:function v8::internal::CodeStub::PrintBaseName(std::ostream&) const: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::clear(std::_Ios_Iostate)'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_base.a(code-stubs.o):code-stubs.cc:function v8::internal::BinaryOpICStub::GenerateAheadOfTime(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::BinaryOpICState const&): error: undefined reference to 'VTT for std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_base.a(code-stubs.o):code-stubs.cc:function v8::internal::BinaryOpICStub::GenerateAheadOfTime(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::BinaryOpICState const&): error: undefined reference to 'VTT for std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_base.a(code-stubs.o):code-stubs.cc:function v8::internal::BinaryOpICStub::GenerateAheadOfTime(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::BinaryOpICState const&): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
C:/Development/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/x86-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.8/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_base.a(code-stubs.o):code-stubs.cc:function v8::internal::BinaryOpICStub::GenerateAheadOfTime(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::BinaryOpICState const&): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
C:/Development/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/x86-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.8/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_base.a(code-stubs.o):code-stubs.cc:function v8::internal::BinaryOpICStub::GenerateAheadOfTime(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::BinaryOpICState const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
<snipped for brevity>
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_libbase.a(platform-posix.o):platform-posix.cc:function v8::base::OS::FPrint(_IO_FILE*, char const*, ...): error: undefined reference to '__vfprintf_chk'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_libbase.a(platform-posix.o):platform-posix.cc:function v8::base::OS::VFPrint(_IO_FILE*, char const*, char*): error: undefined reference to '__vfprintf_chk'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_libbase.a(platform-posix.o):platform-posix.cc:function v8::base::OS::SNPrintF(char*, int, char const*, ...): error: undefined reference to '__vsnprintf_chk'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_libbase.a(platform-posix.o):platform-posix.cc:function v8::base::OS::VSNPrintF(char*, int, char const*, char*): error: undefined reference to '__vsnprintf_chk'
jni/./libs/x86/libv8_libplatform.a(default-platform.o):default-platform.cc:function void std::deque<v8::Task*, std::allocator<v8::Task*> >::_M_push_back_aux<v8::Task* const&>(v8::Task* const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [obj/local/x86/libv8jsevaluator.so] Error 1

12:13:41 Build Finished (took 1s.821ms)
```

As I said, without the attempt to build x86, this is all OK.

Please can anyone point me at where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Often problems like this occur when there's a conflict between libstdc++ and libc++.   The undefined symbol for string-related stuff is a sign of that, as the names are mangled differently between the two "standards"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my source of V8 from 4.1.0.22 to 4.9.385.30 and - after solving a lot of other issues - this problem went away.